# Android SupportFragment hides AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am building an app that uses an Android maps v2 fragment and needs to have 2.3 support. I've got the maps up and running fine, but the AlertDialogs I have are showing up under the map fragment, also a button I had layed out over the fragment does not show. This only happens on a 2.3 device, 4.0 + devices the AlertDialog shows up with no problem.

Here is how I make the AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you the trip is finished?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {});
```

Below is the layout I have for the screen in question:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_duty"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_duty"

        android:layout="@layout/hud_duty"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_pickupHUD"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panel_pickupHUD"

        android:layout="@layout/hud_pickup"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="7"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:orientation="vertical"
 >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapView"

            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wayBillButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/info_black"
            android:layout_weight="1"  />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_waiting_bottom"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panelWaitingBottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout="@layout/panel_driver_info_bottom"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_pickup_bottom"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panelPickupBottom"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout="@layout/panel_pickup_bottom"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_driving_bottom"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/panelDrivingBottom"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout="@layout/panel_driving_bottom"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

I appreciate any assistance in advances, thanks guys.

Comment: Have you any solution for this? I face the same bug.